Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)\frac{1}{2^n}$
Let $p_N(n) = (n-1)/2^n$ be the pmf of $N$ (discrete r.v.), and its CDF simply $F_n(n) = \sum_{i=2}^{n} p_N(n)$. I have proven this series converges to $1$, as is expected.
Assume an event $\zeta$ will occur exactly $N - 2$ times, and we want to find the expected number of times the event will occur. Evidently,
$$
\mathbb{E}[N-2] = \mathbb{E}[N] - 2 = -2 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n(n-1)\frac{1}{2^n}
$$
What does the r.h.s. converge to in this case?

Appeal to the geometric series. Observe that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n = \frac{1}{1-x}
$$
so a twice-differentiation yields
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)x^{n-2} = \frac{2}{(1-x)^3}
$$
Multiply both sides by $x^2$ and let $x=\frac 1 2$ to conclude.
